# Execute sql in a file via sqlcmd

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd, sql-server-2017

I have some insert statements in a `.sql` file.

I want to execute the insert statements via `sqlcmd` and tried to do it like this:

```
sqlcmd -S (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB -i C:\BacklogItems\15298\dbo.ak_funktion_typ.Table.sql
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near 'S'.

What could be the problem with the `-S`?

According to https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4924/execute-sql-server-script-files-with-the-sqlcmd-utility/ the I can provide the server name via this parameter...

I've made sure that the query is in the `SQLCMD Mode`.

Thanks in advance for any tips

Comment: Are you sure it's not talking about a syntax error in the .sql file? That's a SQL error message. If it were a problem with the command itself, you'd get a DOS/Windows error message

Comment: the insert statements in the .sql file are generated by the "Generate Scripts" wizard from the sql server management studio

Comment: still worth checking they're ok, and that there's nothing else wonky in the file. Try executing the statements directly in a SQL GUI. I'm 99.9% sure that the Windows command line doesn't generate "syntax error" reports

Comment: I just tried to execute the statements in the .sql file by hand and it worked without any problems

Comment: I execute the `sqlcmd -S ...` statement directly from the sql server management studio

Comment: well that's your mistake then. sqlcmd is a windows .exe file designed to run from a command line. If you're using SSMS you don't _need_ sqlcmd because you're already in a SQL environment via the GUI. In SSMS you would just open the .sql file using File -> Open from the menu, and execute it. You've entirely missed the point of using the sqlcmd utility.

Comment: But I want to execute the content of 100 .sql files (and possibly multiple times) so I dont want to open them seperately by hand but want to create a script that does it. And I can execute them from ssms by using the SQLCMD mode or what is that for if not? :S

Comment: I'll repeat: _sqlcmd is a windows .exe file designed to run from a command line_. So yeah you can create a script and use it with sqlcmd, but you run it from a windows Command Prompt, not from SSMS. sqlcmd is a separate client for accessing the database, just like SSMS is a client for accessing the database. They are both .exe files underneath, they both run in windows. sqlcmd does not run within SSMS. If you want to run 100 files like this, you might want to create a Windows batch file to do it, which will loop through a folder of .sql files and run sqlcmd repeatedly against each file.

Comment: I think also that your sqlcmd statement will need to include the credentials or method of connecting to the database (either trusted connection based on windows identity, or a username/password, depending how you've set up your server)

Comment: SQLCMD mode is a _mode_ in which you can run the query editor. It _emulates_ the same behaviour you would get if you ran the same queries using the sqlcmd utility. Nowhere in that article does it tell you to actually write `sqlcmd` ...etc into your query editor window.

Comment: ah okay now I understand what you mean, sorry for the confusion. To execute it via sqlcmd-mode I have to write `:r` instead of `sqlcmd`. Thanks for your help, if you add it as answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is because you need to execute `sqlcmd` in a Windows Command Prompt environment, not in a SQL editor environment such as SSMS. `sqlcmd` is a separate executable (.exe) utility which has some equivalence to a GUI such as SSMS, in that it is another type of client program for communicating with the database server. It is not a tool which is used within SSMS itself (or any other SQL client).